# Oracle - Update a Column length completely with #?

Tags: oracle11g, sql-update

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I can't see an answer anywhere on the net so not sure if this is possible.

I am doing a project at the minute where I have to destroy client data and by destroy I mean make the client not identifiable.

I have many tables that I need to create a batch to update certain fields with the # character and several other just to blank them.

Is there any way to have an update statement where you can set the entire width of the column with # instead of specifying each one?

For instance, say on a table called CLIENT we have a NAME column declared as VARCHAR2(10). I am currently doing this:

```
UPDATE CLIENT C SET C.NAME = '##########' WHERE C.ID = xxxxxx;
```

Is there any way to do this where I don't have to specify 10 #'s, something like?

UPDATE CLIENT C SET C.NAME = ALL '#' WHERE C.ID = xxxxxx;

It is just that some fields are 4 characters, some 9, some 10, some 20 etc. If it is not possible then no big drama but I just thought it would be a more tidy approach if it could be done.

Thanks for the help,
Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp_replace().

```
update client 
set name = regexp_replace(name,'[A-Za-z0-9]','#') 
where c.id = xxxxxx;
```

Comment: If name only has alphabets remove 0-9 from the list.

Comment: Great stuff, really helpful and clean.. I really must teach myself regex.. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, another question on the above. If the name is 'MARY' above I get '####' but any way I can completely fill the NAME column to be '##########' regardless how long the name is?

Comment: In that case you can rpad the required number of '#' as patrick has mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

This could be one way to do it. This query will generate an update statement for all VARCHAR2 columns but you have to supply your own WHERE clause manually.

```
select 'update '||table_name||' set '||
listagg(column_name||'= RPAD(''#'', '||data_length||', ''#'')', ', ') within group (order by column_name)
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'CLIENT'
and data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
group by table_name
```